# Централизовать элемент внутри блока

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае возможно централизовать стрелку prev_arrow и next_arrow по горизонтали внутри элементов prev_history и next_history?
Пробовал display: table; margin: 0 auto; , но что-то не получается... Подскажите, как быть в данном случае.
Спасибо

```
 <style>
    .prev_history{float:left;left:0;position:fixed;display:block;height:100%;width:6%;opacity:0}
    .next_history{float:right;right:0;position:fixed;display:block;height:100%;width:6%;opacity:0}
    .prev_history:hover,.next_history:hover{background:#ececef;opacity:1}
    .prev_arrow{float:left;top:40%;left:0;border-top:25px solid transparent;border-right:50px solid #4c4e5a;border-bottom:25px solid transparent;position:fixed;}
    .next_arrow{float:right;top:40%;right:0;border-top:25px solid transparent;border-left:50px solid #4c4e5a;border-bottom:25px solid transparent;position:fixed}
    </style>
    <div class="prev_history" onclick="javascript:history.back();">
       <span class="prev_arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="next_history" onclick="javascript:history.forward();">
       <span class="next_arrow"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: @aliokero, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Задаешь .prev_history ширину и .prev_arrow ширину. А потом делаешь:

```
.prev_arrow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @navi1893, там флоаты, это не поможет.

Comment: @Etki, флоаты вместе с фиксированным позиционированием - это вообще нонсенс. ;) По ходу, я вообще [не пойму, в чём проблема][1]. Ну, может то, что в процентах я бы не задавал ширину, а так...

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/mq7prtht/1/

Comment: Спасибо. Попробовал задать фиксированную ширину, поменять позиционирование у стрелок - не прокатило. ( Может, есть еще варианты?